# Can I add extra property to a MultiUserChat RoomInfo?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

In Smack, we can get the information of a room by RoomInfo. And now I have an extra info(like the location where a room belongs) for a room, how can I do this by smack?

for example, in current smack:

- a admin can set room info(like description of a room) via
  `MultiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(...);`
- and a member can get info(like description of a room) via
  `MultiUserChat.getRoomInfo(...);`